# LiteCoin Wallet balance does not match block-explorer.com

Tags: wallet, blockchain, litecoin, balance

My Litecoin wallet version v0.8.6.2-beta is showing a balance of 26.579 ltc
When I query http://block-explorer.com/address/LejrG23b2HcjqPRbZU8UWFxZhdJTUc75pS it is showing 0 balance.

I just sent 2 ltc to another address from my wallet successfully on 19 Feb 2014. This tx did not show up in the block-explorer.com (currently 20 confirmations), yet it did show the new balance correctly.

http://ltc.blockr.io/api/v1/address/balance/LejrG23b2HcjqPRbZU8UWFxZhdJTUc75pS is also showing a 0 balance.

Thoughts?

Comment: My guess is that's not the only address managed by your wallet.

Comment: I thought the same at first. I did check; and, there is just one wallet. The same thing is happening in my PeerCoin wallet.

Comment: Check all the addresses in your wallet. There could be more than one addresses in a single wallet.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu. Would you know how I can check for more than one wallet?

Comment: A *wallet* manages one or more *addresses*. So checking one single address on block-explorer.com won't give you the whole picture of what's actually in your wallet. The balance of the wallet as a whole is the sum of the balances of all the individual addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Not all of the addresses in your wallet are displayed in the QT client. There are certain addresses called [change addresses](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Change) which your client creates automatically when you send coins and have some left over. Those are still part of your wallet, but are not displayed.